DOMNodeInserted event for a deeply nested element that is added after some XHR call
In an HTML doc, I want to get an event for when a deeply nested element with a certain ID is added. Even some of the ancestors of the element are added conditionally after XHR calls. Is it / how can I do this with the MutationObserver?

When you set an observer on a node it can be configured to observe changes to itself and it's children. If you want to observe an element being wrapped around a certain element, you could observe that by a node higher up in the DOM tree then verify by drilling down with nodeIterator() or treeWalker(). See this post.

Assuming it has an id attribute that's unique in the document, you can use document.getElementById directly in a recursive MutationObserver, example.
